# What is a good way to deploy/reference Alexa Skills on my website

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I have built  a Alexa Skill, but for now it only works for Alexa Device.

I wonder if that is possible I can deploy/reference the Alexa Skill in my website (only text or voice part)?

One use case:

User can say "i am born in xx/xx/xxxx", and Alexa can capture the intent "CaptureBirthdayIntent", so that my website code (Python) can address the intent.

I found many CMS (e.g. Wordpress, Drupal) can do this: https://medium.com/@OPTASY.com/how-to-integrate-alexa-with-your-drupal-8-website-a-step-by-step-guide-5a76c1d74a88. But I am not using those CMS.

It also seems like Alexa Voice Service can do this.

Can anyone give me some reference?

Comment: You do understand that *Alexa skill* means that it's specifically designed to work with an Alexa device? That's why it has the name **Alexa** skill.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, you'll need to use Account Linking, which is an API where the customer links their account at your website and their account with Alexa, and then you'll have a unique ID for the customer that is the same in both your skill and your external app (and is unique to that link between them), so you can sync data between them using a database.

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/account-linking/understand-account-linking.html

You can create your own unique OAuth 2 provider at your web app or use Login with Amazon, Login with Google, Facebook, AWS Cognito... Having your own OAuth provider can make it way easier to get a customer linked and not have them give up, because adding in third parties (LwA, Google, FB, AWS) adds extra logins/authorizations to complete the process.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Dialogflow to do this. Make a chatbot with similar intents and map the endpoint to Alexa endpoints and should work. I am sure you can easily work it out if you have made an Alexa skill.

Comment: I mean I will use my own Alexa Skill.